# Ensure "done()" is called JS Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mocha.js

Trying to insert new element into my mongoDB database, when I use terminal to 'npm run test' it gives me this error:

```
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure 
"done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

Here is my code for saving an element into my DB:

```
const mocha = require('mocha');
const assert = require('assert');
const PPB = require('../Models/Pingpongballs');

describe('Saving records', function() {
  it('Saves record to db', function(done) {
    var ppball = new PPB ({
      amount: 5
    });

    ppball.save().then(function() {
      assert(ppball.isNew === false);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mocha, for async tests you could call `done` callback or return the promise. You're getting this error, because your test is failed, and you haven't `catch` block to call `done` with error:

```
describe('Saving records', function() {
  it('Saves record to db', function() {
    var ppball = new PPB ({
      amount: 5
    });

    return ppball.save().then(function(){
      assert(ppball.isNew === false);
      return null;
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: You could remove the return null

Comment: @Denis, As a practice shows it's better always return or throw from inside `then()` function. [There is](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/warning-explanations.html#warning-a-promise-was-created-in-a-handler-but-was-not-returned-from-it) described one of the reasons why you should do so.

Comment: @alexmac, I understand the problem if it was a Promise running, but the assert is sync code, would it still be a good pratice? And thanks for the info, I didnt know that

Comment: @Denis, bluebird doesn't know that `assert` is sync code, and still shows warning. So I prefer call `return` always, to not forget to do that when it really is necessary.